# Connected component a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry

If S is a regular surface and **compact** then S has a finite number of connected components.

Any suggestion, please.

Thank you all.

Regular surface:

$S\subset{\mathbb{R}^3}$ is aregular surface if, for each $p\in{S}$ exists a map $X:U\to{V\cap{S}}$ ($U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $V$ open in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $p\in{V}$ ) such that:

i) $X$ is differentiable.

ii) $X$ is a homeomorphism.

iii) The differential $dX_q:\mathbb{R}^2\to{\mathbb{R}^3}$ is one to one for each $q\in{U}$.

Comment: What's your definition of regular surface? In my text, I require connectedness.

Comment: The Definition the book of Manfredo P. Do Carmo, Diffrential Geometry of curves and surfaces.

Comment: Not everybody has this book, you should copy the definition in your question.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to prove is false, consider the union of infinitely many pairwise disjoint nonempty open disks in a hyperplane in the 3-space.

Edit: now that you added compactness assumption, the answer is positive. The reason is that every surface (no need for regularity) is locally homeomorphic to the open round 2-disk (by the definition). The latter is connected since it is path connected. Thus, you have an open cover of your surface by connected subsets. By compactness, there is a finite subcover. Hence, your surface is the union if finitely many connected sets, hence has only finite number of connected components.

Comment: Or a countable collection of disjoint spheres. Nothing in that definition to rule it out.

Comment: Yes, of course as long as the collection is locally finite.

Comment: I'm sorry, S is compact.

Comment: The idea is prove that S is locally connected but do not know

Comment: That's why I asked for the precise definition. It is immediate that every surface is locally connected (since open disk is connected).

Comment: Nice proof in the edit. You could also just use the open cover by the connected components themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are infinitely any connected components. Then there is an infinite sequence of points such that each term belongs to a distinct connected component.  If the surface is compact, it lies in a compact region of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Compactness provides a convergent subsequence. Think about the limit point and the regularity condition.